# Mapping cone of covering projection $\pi: S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$ and $\pi: S^{2n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

We can think about a cone of a continuous map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ as following. We take a cone of $X$, let's denote it by $CX$ and attach it at the bottom to $Y$ by the following rule:
$$
x \mapsto f(x)
$$
For example, let's take identity map
$$
\text{Id}: S^1 \rightarrow S^1
$$
it's easy to see that

$$
\text{Con(Id)} \sim D^2
$$

More generally if we take identity map from $n$ dimensional sphere to itself, the cone of identity map is $n+1$ dimensional disk:
$$\text{Id}: S^n \rightarrow S^n$$
$$\text{Con(Id)} \sim D^{n+1}$$
Let's look at something more interesting, namely 2-fold covering of real projective space:
$$\pi: S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$$
I want to calculate the cone of this covering map.
To do it, we should glue $CS^n$ with $\mathbb{R}P^n$ by the map $\pi$, as i mentioned $CS^n \sim_\varphi D^{n+1}$ ($\varphi$ is homeomorphism), so we should glue $D^{n+1}$ with $\mathbb{R}P^n$ by the map $\pi \circ \varphi$, but i can't understand what the resulting space looks like? And the same question for complex projective space case and covering map
$$
\pi : S^{2n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n
$$
?In commentaries it was mentioned that it should be $\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}$ and $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}$ respectivly, in real case we can imagine it, using disk model of projective space, but in complex case it's not so obvious.

Comment: The resulting spaces are $\Bbb{R}P^{n+1}$ and $\Bbb{C}P^{n+1}$ respectively.

Comment: @Zerox I have no idea why it's true and why it "should be true" (i can't  draw any picture), even in 1 dimensional case

Comment: @Zerox, may be i understood, it's true because we can think of gluing disk to projective space as gluing disks boundary in good way, as we do in disks model of projective space

Comment: @Zerox but with complex case i coudn't understood why it's $n+1$ dimensional projective space, because the line intersects the $S^{2n+2}$ by circle, not by 2 points, it even looks not true

Comment: Try the "chart decomposition", namely $\Bbb{R}P^{n+1}=\Bbb{R}^{n+1} \cup \Bbb{R}P^{n}$ and $\Bbb{C}P^{n+1}=\Bbb{C}^{n+1} \cup \Bbb{C}P^{n}$. Use $\Bbb{C}P^{n} \cong \Bbb{C}^{n+1} /  \Bbb{C}^{\times}$ to deduce that $\Bbb{C}P^{n} \cong S^{2n+1} / S^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping cones are indeed the adjunction spaces obtained from $\mathbb KP^n$ by attaching a cell $D^k$ of dimension $k = n$ for $\mathbb K = \mathbb R$ and $k = 2n+1$ for $\mathbb K = \mathbb C$ via the attaching map $\pi$. The resulting spaces are $\mathbb KP^{n+1}$.

This is nicely treated in Hatcher's "[Algebraic Topology](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATpage.html)" Examples 0.4 and 0.6.

But you should not expect that you can really "imagine it". The proofs need some very formsl arguments.